# After using cx_freeze I get exception _imaging c module is not installed

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I use Python 3 and unofficial PIL module. My code works fine. But after using cx_freeze I get exception "_imaging c module is not installed".

What can I do with this problem? All solutions that I found were about Python 2.X and Linux OS. I need the solution for Windows and Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem. _imagingtk needs ImageTk imported first. So this code works:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import _imagingtk
```

And there is no more problem with cx_freeze. But really I don't understand what the real reason of this bug was. I just guessed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the problem with _imaging. I just needed to add to my code:

```
from PIL import _imaging
```

But there is one new problem. After using cx_freeze, I get "No module named _imagingtk".

But the solution like previous doesn't work.
If I try:

```
from PIL import _imagingtk
```

I get "DLL load failed".

File _imagingtk.pyd exists in my PIL folder but I can't load this module even from Python-interprer.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i know of that that can happen is if the _imagingtk.pyd is not for your python version.
Oh, could you post the link to the unofficial version? I've been searching for it for awhile.